# How to rollback a channel to a previous Nixos generation?

Tags: nixos, nix

```
$ sudo nix-env --list-generations --profile /nix/var/nix/profiles/system
...
 600   2020-01-25 21:01:11   
 601   2020-02-03 13:44:19   
 602   2020-02-09 14:06:20   
 603   2020-02-09 14:11:11   
 604   2020-02-11 00:02:43   
 605   2020-02-13 12:26:22   
 606   2020-02-16 16:40:02   (current)
```

How could I get the commit / channel generation (is this a thing?) for a Nixos generation - and potentially rollback the channel to it?

Or in other words, how can I rollback my 'channel state' to what it was at generation 605?

---

Why I want to know is because I did a `sudo nix-channel --update`, and `sudo nixos-rebuild switch` few days ago - however whatever package updates took place - resulted in an unstable system.

So to mitigate this, I booted and continue to use an old generation (`605`).

I now want to update a specific package in my Nixos system configuration, and base the changes on `605` as opposed to the latest `606`.

---

I did find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39090387/how-to-undo-nix-channel-update (`nix-channel --rollback..`) however I may have updated the channels a few times - so the 'last' channel state might not be what I need.

I did notice you can specify a channel generation number as a parameter to this command - but I'm not sure what is the relationship between that and the nixos generation? It does not seem to be the same thing as I tried for `605` with the following results:

```
sudo nix-channel --rollback 605
error: generation 605 does not exist
error: program '/nix/store/cs47wjxwiqgyl1nkjnksyf3s2rb93piq-nix-2.3.2/bin/nix-env' failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you want `sudo nix-channel --rollback` ?  For example, you may also manually inspect `/nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels-*/manifest.nix` – those contain name, commit hash, etc.

Comment: Hmm possibly but in my case I need to rollback to a revision prior to the last. I've updated the question with more info.

Comment: 605 is surely an incorrect number.  The series of channel updates (your `nix-channel --update` runs) is "independent" of your `nix-env` updates.  If you want the previous one, you just don't specify any number.  It can be useful to `ls -l /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/root/channels-*`, as you see timestamps when you did those runs.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR;

> **Profile generations and channel generations are different things.** Channel generations track changes to the list of *available*
> derivations (packages), and profile generations track the *installed*
> derivations and their versions. `ls -g /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/my_user_name/` will tell you at a
> glance everything you need to know about the current generation of
> each.

/TLDR;

Vladimir's answer is perfectly correct, but easily dismissed due to the scary long path ;)

When you update a channel:

```
nix-channel --update <my-channel-alias>
```

You advance the current user's channel generation by one. Only `my-channel-alias` was affected, but this still causes a whole new generation to be built and your environment to reference it.

Unfortunately, `nix-channel` has no switch to list channel generations. This is where the long path comes in. You can see that `channels` links to `channels-4-link` for the user `my_user_name`. Therefore, `my_user_name`'s currently selected channel generation is 4.

```bsh
ls -g /nix/var/nix/profiles/per-user/my_user_name/
  channels -> channels-4-link                                                      
  channels-1-link -> /nix/store/57904rflsfh46y7fxi62rzc7sidc9vmq-user-environment                                                      
  channels-2-link -> /nix/store/j5j5avwf07a2ajr3jszj9vv8l5ybgycm-user-environment                                                      
  channels-3-link -> /nix/store/xb0accm8k1zsll5wrxck7gj0xbdv8zk7-user-environment                                                      
  channels-4-link -> /nix/store/dlh9wlpx59lifgni06q0vwgymshn9jja-user-environment                                                      
  channels-5-link -> /nix/store/8wymqxsdy3m7gmh6f21m49hl98gy75aa-user-environment                                                      
  channels-6-link -> /nix/store/3sf1c989bbfrrxrpr235xqjqvd89apsi-user-environment                                                      
  profile -> profile-1-link                                                      
  profile-10-link -> /nix/store/kwlgbfbpwjhgb42bp7c899l8a1cyjdcl-user-environment                                                      
  profile-1-link -> /nix/store/57904rflsfh46y7fxi62rzc7sidc9vmq-user-environment                                                      
  profile-2-link -> /nix/store/c614r1kmrg9nsx2qvd944k5afj49qim7-user-environment                                                      
  profile-3-link -> /nix/store/57904rflsfh46y7fxi62rzc7sidc9vmq-user-environment                                                      
  profile-4-link -> /nix/store/2blnby22dvc92i9ahprwkl504ngj75ad-user-environment                                                      
  profile-5-link -> /nix/store/ahd9dzfkgvyfqdkdw8cw8w8dyqak66b4-user-environment                                                      
  profile-6-link -> /nix/store/gbjmn5rcjl4iscfvgms9hk26vhpr6pv2-user-environment                                                      
  profile-7-link -> /nix/store/57904rflsfh46y7fxi62rzc7sidc9vmq-user-environment                                                      
  profile-8-link -> /nix/store/k50s7rb4gz3pibd0r8136y628al74www-user-environment                                                      
  profile-9-link -> /nix/store/57904rflsfh46y7fxi62rzc7sidc9vmq-user-environment
```

In contrast, profile (user environments) generations are advanced with the following `nix-env` operations:

```
--install
--update
--uninstall
```

As mentioned in the man page for nix-env.

```
man nix-env | grep "new user environment"
```

And the different profile generations for the current user are easily queried with:

```
nix-env --list-generations
```

Comment: Great writeup. Some minor nitpicks.. "but the mutation of even one channel requires the change to be recorded in a new generation." Worded a bit strangely. More that, you can build a new generation / environment that references an updated channel.